# Typesetting commas in bracket vector notation

Tags: punctuation, fractions, vector

This is my first post so please go easy on me.

I am writing a vector using the bracket notation as shown below:

```latex
\[
     \vec{u} = \left\langle \frac{1}{10} , \frac{1}{3} \right\rangle
\]
```

[image: Fraction Valued Vector, comma centered vertically]

The comma is typeset in the center of the fractions in line with the Vinculum (division line), and I'm wondering if there is a way to put it at the bottom in line with the denominators?

Or, is this the proper typesetting notation, and I should just be okay with where it is at?

Comment: Welcome! You *can* move the comma down, e.g. with `\[\vec{u} = \left\langle \frac{1}{10} \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{,} \frac{1}{3} \right\rangle\]` (which requires `amsmath`), but I personally wouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that works perfectly!  Outside of personal preference, is there reason I should choose NOT to typeset the comma this way?

Comment: Well, this depends on whom you ask. There are some users who are very religious about these things (and go as far as proclaiming their conventions are "correct" while others are "incorrect"). I personally think that if you have a good reason why you want to do that, go for it. However, for me the comma separates the two fractions, and it is at the right place in you screen shot. Please also note that the `braket` package may make it more convenient to typeset such bra-kets.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and your explanation!  I don't think that the `braket` package is a good fit for this particular document, but I appreciate the suggestion.  I think that I will post an answer to this question based on your solution and how I intend to implement it into my code.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Shaun Just think to `\left\langle\frac{1}{10},1\right\rangle`; where would you put the comma? Midway?

Comment: @egreg Fair point.  So then I assume your suggestion would be to just leave the comma where it is originally set in general?

Comment: @Shaun Exactly. I won't say it's the correct choice, but the most reasonable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As User [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat?tab=profile) suggested, including `\includepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble, the following code produces the desired result:

`\[\vec{u} = \left\langle \frac{1}{10} \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{,} \frac{1}{3} \right\rangle\]`

For my implementation, I've defined a new macro as a shortcut in the preamble as:

`\newcommand{\fraccomma}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{,}}`

Then the final code produces:

```latex
\[
     \vec{u} = \left\langle \frac{1}{10} \fraccomma \frac{1}{3} \right\rangle
\]
```

[image: Comma in line with denominators]

**Edit:**

However, as User [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) also pointed out, when implementing this solution we should also consider that it might not be appropriate if not all of the terms are fractions.  In that event, then a more appropriate typesetting would be to just leave the comma in it's default position: `\vec{u} = \left\langle \frac{1}{10} , 3 \right\rangle`